# Diff function transposes matrix when used with apply over rows

Tags: r, matrix, apply, difference

I need to find the difference between columns in a matrix. The `diff()` function will work with a matrix for differences between rows for each column, but I need differences between columns for each row. I tried using `apply()` with `diff()` over the row index, but this returns a transposed result. Why does it return the transpose and am I using it incorrectly?

```
# make a small sample matrix
m <- matrix(seq(1, 20, by = 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 10)

# apply the diff function to the rows, I expect a 2 by 10 matrix here, should I just transpose it?
apply(m, 1, diff)

   [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    2    2
 [2,]    2    2
 [3,]    2    2
 [4,]    2    2
 [5,]    2    2
 [6,]    2    2
 [7,]    2    2
 [8,]    2    2
 [9,]    2    2
```

Comment: Can you just transpose to rows and then back again? `t(diff(t(m)))` ?

Comment: Aren't you already computing the differences over the columns? After all, `apply(m, 1, diff)[,1]` is `diff(m[1,])`.

Comment: That's just how `apply` works, it has nothing to do with `diff`. Yes, simply transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the "transpose effect" of `apply`:

According to `?apply`, `apply` applies a function to the row vectors (`MARGIN = 1`) or column vectors (`MARGIN = 2`) of an array (e.g. a `matrix`) and returns

> an array of dimension ‘c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])’ if ‘n > 1’

where n is the length of the vector returned by an individual call of the function to either the row or column vector.

So in your case `dim(m)` is `2 10` (i.e. a `2x10` matrix) and `MARGIN = 1`, so the array dimension of the return object is `9 2`, which means a `9x2` matrix (as `diff` returns a vector of length `n=9`).

You can see the same "transpose effect" when you do

```
apply(m, 1, c)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    3    4
# [3,]    5    6
# [4,]    7    8
# [5,]    9   10
# [6,]   11   12
# [7,]   13   14
# [8,]   15   16
# [9,]   17   18
#[10,]   19   20
```

Comment: The `diff()` function returns a vector of length 9 so should n be nine then? It returns a 9 by 2 matrix?

Comment: @user29609 Yes, you're right; clearly I can't count ....;-) I've made a correction.

Answer (score 0):

If all what's confusing you is the format `9 2` instead of `2 9`, then you are right, just transpose it.

Because you very well are already computing the differences over the columns, i.e.

```
for(k in 1:nrow(m)) diff(m[k,])
```

yields exactly what you already have. A simple `t(apply(m, 1, diff))` will do the trick.

```
> t(apply(m, 1, diff))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
```

---

**PS** You can't get a `10 2`/`2 10` structure because `diff` will obviously return an element of size `n - 1`.